# Wordpress meta_value query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Losing my mind.  Long time customizer of Wordpress. THIS query has me baffled.

I have a record in wp_post meta where the following exist:

- meta_id = 32765
- post_id = 4376
- meta_key = frontpage
- meta_value = frontpage

the following query returns nothing:

```
if($events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'frontpage';" )){
                    print_r($events);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you enabled WP_DEBUG mode to see errors? Maybe some errors are being displayed?

Comment: JUST enabled DEBUG - checking through errors there...

Comment: Another check: Have you globalized $wpdb? like: `global $wpdb;`?

Comment: Not sure the problem is related, (not sure HOW it could be), but I get an error `Trying to get property of non-object in E:\blahblahblah\wp-content\themes\Trailmeister\functions\taxonomies.php on line 81`

Comment: Which line is the line 81?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm creating an OUTSIDE page that starts with `define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
` and includes the code above.  Trying to get info from specific custom post types into this page that isn't really part of the wordpress system, except that it should include bits from the custom posts

Comment: Line 81 of the Taxonomies.php is `$term_obj = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxo);`

Comment: I should note that I'm getting those errors EVEN WITHOUT THE INCLUDED CODE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45765/discussion-between-david-mcclave-and-omar-tariq)

Answer (score 1):

```
global $wpdb;
if($events = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_value = 'frontpage';" )){
                    print_r($events);
}
```

Comment: This code makes the page just go white - not even errors will show

Comment: ACTUALLY... this code doesn't disable the page when I turn off DEBUG... I may have bigger problems

Comment: Never forget to enable WP_DEBUG while you are in the development phase.

Comment: @DeFeNdog I can see it answered by 'Omar Tariq' `:-/`. If you mean to say the correct answer then maybe because his problem is not solved by my code.

Comment: I meant to comment under David McClave. I up-voted you on it for a partial answer. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

OK, for my particular issue, Thanks to Omar Tariq, I have the answer - the page I was making is outside of my Wordpress system, and the theme I am using is a heavily-modified and customized theme with many custom post types.  The solution is to SIMPLY use the MYSQL API in PHP, instead of using $wpdb.  This was fast, simple and easy.  I wish I could delete my question... I'm a bit embarrassed.